# I am needing to fix a Zero Division error

Tags: python, math

```
# Trapezoidal Method

# Define function to integrate
def f(x):
    return x**(-1/3)

# Implementing trapezoidal method
def trapezoidal(x0, xn, n):
    # calculating step size
    h = (xn - x0) / n

    # Finding sum
    integration = f(x0) + f(xn)

    for i in range(1, n):
        k = x0 + i * h
        integration = integration + 2 * f(k)

    # Finding final integration value
    integration = integration * h / 2

    return integration

# Input section
lower_limit = float(input("Enter lower limit of integration: "))
upper_limit = float(input("Enter upper limit of integration: "))
sub_interval = int(input("Enter number of sub intervals: "))

# Call trapezoidal() method and get result
result = trapezoidal(lower_limit, upper_limit, sub_interval)
print("Integration result by Trapezoidal method is: %0.6f" % (result))
```

I am clearly doing something wrong with the exponent. the error tells me 0.0mcaannot be raised to a negative power, but i initialized it at 0.0.

Comment: If you try 0**-9 on a calculator what do you get?

Comment: `f` is not defined at `x = 0`, so you can't integrate over an interval containing that point. The value of `f` increase towards infinity as `x` approaches 0 from the right. Pick a positive lower limit (or a negative upper limit).

Comment: I guess I am not understanding because this integral is able to be solved analytically as (3/2)

Comment: Sure, but you can't blindly apply approximation methods. Applying the trapezoidal method as is would require `f(0)` to be defined, which it is not. The reasonable approach is to use an arbitrarily small value instead and quantify the error.

Comment: Hello, We can't really help if we don't know `lower_limit, upper_limit, sub_interval`. Could you please remove the three `input()` lines, and replace them with hardcoded values so we can see exactly what input you gave? Using the [edit] button.

Comment: @Clay you cannot do a power to a negative number on ZERO

Comment: *"I guess I am not understanding because this integral is able to be solved analytically as (3/2)"* <<< Yes, the true integral can be calculated, but you're not calculating the true integral, you're doing an approximation using trapezoids. The approximation by trapezoids doesn't work if one of those trapezoids is infinite. In addition to pick the number of sub_intervals, you should pick a small x0 close to 0 but not equal to 0.

Comment: Your code appears to work correctly. If you try `trapezoidal(0.01, 1, 10)` you'll get a result already pretty close to 1.5. And if you try `trapezoidal(0.00001, 1, 10000)` then it's even closer.

Comment: As many folks have pointed out already, what you're "clearly doing wrong" is using the trapezoidal method in a way that it cannot be used. It can only be used over intervals that are continuous, which is not true in this case at f(0). However, there's nothing stopping you from running it from some tiny non-zero value.